# Generate word matching from set of user inputs

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to design a program that will take user input to create a title, keywords, and a set of matching descriptions. Once the user enters this into the UI and clicks generate_html the section should disappear. Then the word matching html should be generated with the user data.

For example, the input page would look like the figure shown below:

[image]

The word matching html would look like the figure shown below:

[image]

The code for the user input is the following

User Input:

```
<center>
  <div class="inputBoxes">
    <table id="tablestyle">
      <td>
        <input id="el1" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="el2" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="el3" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="el4" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="el5" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

Result in HTML:

```
<center>
  <div class="inputBoxes">
    <table id="tablestyle">
      <td>
        <input id="dl1" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="dl2" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="dl3" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="dl4" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="dl5" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
<center>
  <center>
    <span style="padding: 3px">
              <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="generate_html()">generate html</button>
            </span>
  </center>
```

The code for the description and word matching is

```
<center>
    <div class="source">
      <div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s2" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s3" class="draggyBox-large"></div>
      <div id="s4" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s5" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
    </div>
  </center>
  <table id="tablestyle">
    <tr id="row1">
      <td>
        <div id="t1" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d1">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row2">
      <td>
        <div id="t2" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d2">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row3">
      <td>
        <div id="t3" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d3">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row4">
      <td>
        <div id="t4" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d4">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row5">
      <td>
        <div id="t5" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d5">
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
```

The generate_html method is shown below

```
function generate_html() {
      el1 = document.getElementById("el1").value
      el2 = document.getElementById("el2").value
      el3 = document.getElementById("el3").value
      el4 = document.getElementById("el4").value
      el5 = document.getElementById("el5").value
      s1 = document.getElementById("s1")
      s2 = document.getElementById("s2")
      s3 = document.getElementById("s3")
      s4 = document.getElementById("s4")
      s5 = document.getElementById("s5")
      dl1 = document.getElementById("dl1").value
      dl2 = document.getElementById("dl2").value
      dl3 = document.getElementById("dl3").value
      dl4 = document.getElementById("dl4").value
      dl5 = document.getElementById("dl5").value
      d1 = document.getElementById("d1")
      d2 = document.getElementById("d2")
      d3 = document.getElementById("d3")
      d4 = document.getElementById("d4")
      d5 = document.getElementById("d5")
      s1.innerHTML = el1
      s2.innerHTML = el2
      s3.innerHTML = el3
      s4.innerHTML = el4
      s5.innerHTML = el5
      d3.innerHTML = dl1
      d4.innerHTML = dl2
      d5.innerHTML = dl3
      d1.innerHTML = dl4
      d2.innerHTML = dl5

      answer = el4+": "+dl4+"\n"+el5+": "+dl5+"\n"+el1+": "+dl1+"\n"+el2+": "+dl2+"\n"+el3+": "+dl3
      console.log(answer)
    }
```

As stated above, I'd like to break this up into two sections such that when the user clicks the generate_html button the section transitions to the word matching html. If anyone could provide advice on how to achieve this I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] and explain what does not work

Comment: This works. I'm trying to minimize what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is essentially, "How do I change the visibility of parts of the DOM on user input (e.g. the press of a button)?" The most basic answer is to use the [CSS visibility property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) and set it in javascript via the [HTML DOM style property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp).

I've translated your code into a working snippet below. See my comments inline for what I've changed. A couple of notes:

1. You didn't provide the table styling, or any other styling, for that matter, so it's unstyled in the snippet. Also, you set the tables to `id="tablestyle"` when I think you meant `class="tablestyle"`, so I made that change. Having multiple elements with the same `id` is **always a bad idea**.
2. Even if the table were styled, one would be hard-pressed to get it looking like your screenshot. I suspect you have some styling that puts the table inline with all the `draggyBox`es, but that seems rather clunkly to me, and also violates the `div` (new line) v. `span` (inline) rule. For a more modern approach, I would recommend familiarizing yourself with [flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/), which you can use pretty easily to replicate something like your screenshot.

```js
function generate_html() {
      el1 = document.getElementById("el1").value
      el2 = document.getElementById("el2").value
      el3 = document.getElementById("el3").value
      el4 = document.getElementById("el4").value
      el5 = document.getElementById("el5").value
      s1 = document.getElementById("s1")
      s2 = document.getElementById("s2")
      s3 = document.getElementById("s3")
      s4 = document.getElementById("s4")
      s5 = document.getElementById("s5")
      dl1 = document.getElementById("dl1").value
      dl2 = document.getElementById("dl2").value
      dl3 = document.getElementById("dl3").value
      dl4 = document.getElementById("dl4").value
      dl5 = document.getElementById("dl5").value
      d1 = document.getElementById("d1")
      d2 = document.getElementById("d2")
      d3 = document.getElementById("d3")
      d4 = document.getElementById("d4")
      d5 = document.getElementById("d5")
      s1.innerHTML = el1
      s2.innerHTML = el2
      s3.innerHTML = el3
      s4.innerHTML = el4
      s5.innerHTML = el5
      d3.innerHTML = dl1
      d4.innerHTML = dl2
      d5.innerHTML = dl3
      d1.innerHTML = dl4
      d2.innerHTML = dl5
      
      // get the input and results sections and flip their visibilities
      document.getElementById("input-section").style.visibility = "hidden"
      document.getElementById("results-section").style.visibility = "visible"
      

      answer = el4+": "+dl4+"\n"+el5+": "+dl5+"\n"+el1+": "+dl1+"\n"+el2+": "+dl2+"\n"+el3+": "+dl3
      console.log(answer)
    }
```

```html
<!-- Added input-section div so that we can control its visibility -->
<div id="input-section">
  <center>
    <div class="inputBoxes">
      <table class="tablestyle">
        <td>
          <input id="el1" type="text" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="el2" type="text" value="2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="el3" type="text" value="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="el4" type="text" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="el5" type="text" value="5">
        </td>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBoxes">
      <table class="tablestyle">
        <td>
          <input id="dl1" type="text" value="6">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dl2" type="text" value="7">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dl3" type="text" value="8">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dl4" type="text" value="9">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dl5" type="text" value="10">
        </td>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 3px">
                <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="generate_html()">generate html</button>
    </div>
  </center> 
</div>

<!-- Added results-section div so that we can control its visibility,
     initially set to "hidden" -->
<div id="results-section" style="visibility: hidden">
  <center>
    <div class="source">
      <div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s2" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s3" class="draggyBox-large"></div>
      <div id="s4" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
      <div id="s5" class="draggyBox-small"></div>
    </div>
  </center>
  <table class="tablestyle">
    <tr id="row1">
      <td>
        <div id="t1" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d1">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row2">
      <td>
        <div id="t2" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d2">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row3">
      <td>
        <div id="t3" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d3">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row4">
      <td>
        <div id="t4" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d4">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="row5">
      <td>
        <div id="t5" class="ltarget"></div>
      </td>
      <td id = "d5">
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</div>
```